# Reading a csv file header which contains a utf-8 character

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way by which I can check if a csv file contains a header without importing any modules like the csv or panda module? I keep getting an error when I try to use readlines as the header contains a utf-8 character (a degree symbol).

Answer (score 0):

You know that the header of a csv file is its first line separated by commas.

By opening the file and reading its first line you can obtain the information that you need:

```
f = open('file.csv', 'r', encoding='utf-8') #open file
headers = f.readline().split(',') #get headers list
f.close() #close file
```

Comment: Yes I do know this, but my header contains a degree symbol and so I am getting an error as it cannot be read.  ```Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 3, in <module>
    headers = file.readline().split(',')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 40: invalid start byte```

Comment: you have to specify the encoding while opening the file, I modified my answer.
Next time specify the error by putting it explicitly in the Question

Comment: I am still getting the same error as before even after modifying my code

Comment: You have to know which encoding is used to encode your file because it's not utf-8 if it's failing, then change 'utf-8' with your specific encoding.